# Process sparse data in performant way

Tags: java, java-8

I cannot think of a better Title for the issue. Sorry about that.If somebody can think of a better title feel free to change it.

```
Rule {
    String key;
    String t1; // First level
    String t2;
    String t3; // Last level
    Object value;
}

RuleHolder {
    Collection<Rule> rules;
}
```

Sample data can be in RuleHolder as follows (Order can be different)

```
key     t1   t2   t3   value 
 A      a    -    -     m
 A      a    b    -     mm
 A      a    b    c     mmm
 B      a    -    -     n
 C      a    -    -     p
 C      a    b    -     pp
```

Desired result:

```
Key A   ->   mmm
Key B   ->   n
Key C   ->   pp
```

Now how can I achieve the desired result in a performant way? Further to add more complexity how can i get the best value for single key provided t1,t2,t3 like `getBestValue(key,t1,t2,t3)` Possible that for combination of t1,t2,t3 no value is there.

> My try is as follows :

Step1:
First prepare a Map from Collection rules;

```
Map<key, Collection<Rule>>
```

Step2: Inside a key context , Go through all the rules and than pick up the last level defined value.

Comment: You could make the collection sorted so you can always find the one you want on lookup.

Comment: What should happen if there are two rules with t1, t2 and t3 defined?

Comment: @Tunaki Two such rules are not allowed so such situation will never occur.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Stream API, you indeed need to have 2 separate Stream pipeline:

- The first will create a `Map<String, Rule>` with a key pointing to the rule to keep
- The second will map that first result into a new `Map<String, Object>` where we just keep the value of the rule

The first map is created with the `toMap` collector and handles duplicate keys by selecting the value having the most non-null level element. So it first checks for `t3` and select the rule where it is non-null; if none exists, it keeps the rule where `t2` is non-null; etc. Since those are hard-coded variables, we can't make it really dynamic, other than by involving reflection.

Finally, the last map is also created by the `toMap` collector with a simple remapping of the value.

```
Map<String, Rule> ruleMap =
    rules.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        r -> r.key,
        r -> r,
        (r1, r2) -> { // a bit ugly but it comes from the fact that t1, t2 an t3 are hard-coded
            if (r1.t3 != null) return r1;
            if (r2.t3 != null) return r2;
            if (r1.t2 != null) return r1;
            if (r2.t2 != null) return r2;
            if (r1.t1 != null) return r1;
            if (r2.t1 != null) return r2;
            return r1;
        }
    ));

Map<String, Object> result = 
    ruleMap.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().value));

System.out.println(result); // prints "{A=mmm, B=n, C=pp}" for your example
```

---

To make it dynamic, we need to add some magic. Given a list of fields, we can map it into a `List<MethodHandle>`

```
List<String> fields = Arrays.asList("t3", "t2", "t1");
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
List<MethodHandle> handles = fields.stream().map(s -> {
    try {
        return lookup.findGetter(Rule.class, s, String.class);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then we can use that list to return the most appropriate rule in case of duplicate:

```
Map<String, Rule> ruleMap =
    rules.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        r -> r.key,
        r -> r,
        (r1, r2) -> {
            return handles.stream().map(h -> {
                try {
                    if (h.invoke(r1) != null) return r1;
                    if (h.invoke(r2) != null) return r2;
                    return null;
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    throw new AssertionError(t);
                }
            }).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(r1);
        }
    ));
```